# REGEX to Find Rows Containing Opening and Closing Parentheses in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have tried:

```
....WHERE fieldname REGEXP '.*\(.*\).*';
```

But this returns every record in the table.

Comment: Use `WHERE fieldname REGEXP '\\(.*\\)';` or just `LIKE '%(%)%'`

Comment: This was my starting point but to my shock and amazement, its leaving out all the records that start with a parenthesized word.

Comment: So, you want to avoid returning those where parentheses appear at the start? It is not part of your question.

Comment: I want to return all rows having parentheses. I'm saying your suggestion is not returning records that have the field starting with parenthesis.

Comment: It is not true, please check the fiddle I added to my answer.

Comment: So, do you just need to check if there are `(` and `)` in any order in the entries? Do you need to also get `no )(test`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use double backslashes when escaping a regex special metacharacter in a REGEXP pattern. Also, since REGEXP also finds partial matches, you do not need the `.*` at the start/end.

So, you could fix the expression as

```
WHERE fieldname REGEXP '\\(.*\\)';
```

Or just use `LIKE` where `%` matches any amount of arbitrary chars (but must match the whole entry unlike `REGEXP`):

```
WHERE fieldname LIKE '%(%)%';
```

A [MySQL fiddle](http://rextester.com/HORC3611):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t (word varchar(255));
INSERT INTO t (word)
VALUES
    ('test (here)'),
    ('test (here) test'),
    ('(here) test'),
    ('test no'),
    ('no test');

SELECT * FROM t WHERE word REGEXP '\\(.*\\)';

SELECT * FROM t WHERE word LIKE '%(%)%';
```

[image]

To get entries like `text ) and ( here`, you may use

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE word REGEXP '\\(.*\\)|\\).*\\(';

SELECT * FROM t WHERE word LIKE '%(%)%' OR word LIKE '%)%(%';
```

See [another fiddle](http://rextester.com/VFGVR81235).

Comment: It's skipping all records that start with a parenthesized word. I'm still trying to see if there are other cases it misses.

Comment: @user1729972: See my MySQL fiddle results. The issue is out there, not with my solution.

Comment: @user1729972 - Let's see the text that is failing for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - add some examples with unbalanced parens and right paren before left and nothing between parens.

Answer (score 1):

LIKE would be more efficient than REGEXP, but to answer in REGEXP terms...

I suspect the OP wants parentheses to be somewhere in the middle of row text.

The problem with the REGEXP supplied is that expressions are greedy.

As soon as the .* finishes matching, it has already soaked up the entire record.

Try making the first two .* expressions as [^(]*( and [^)]*) and removing the final .* as it is superfluous.

```
'[^\\(]*\\([^\\)]*\\)'
```

Basically, this expression says

- Look for zero or more non ( characters

  - then look for a single ( character
  - then look for zero or more non ) characters
  - then look for a single ) character

The () may be anywhere in the record and may contain zero or more characters inside the ().

Might I suggest fiddling in https://regex101.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Very true about the superfluity though.

Comment: Use  `'[^\\(]*\\([^\\)]*\\)'` for MySQL, the regexp I provided worked with `egrep`

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html just *before* user comments begin.